# Is there a way to better explain the || operator?

Tags: c#, logic

I’m using C# in Unity. I have a script where there’s an option to have a specific bool in another script true, and/or have the script null. This doesn’t work, why?

```
if(ScriptB.giveCookie = true || ScriptB = null)
{
    GiveCookie();
}
```

I would think GiveCookie(); would work ONLY if ScriptB is not null and ScriptB.giveCookie is true, or ScriptB is nonexistent…

Comment: `ScriptB.giveCookie = true` is assigning `true` to the variable and then checking if it is true. Spoilers, it always is so the second part is also evaluated. You probably meant `ScriptB.giveCookie == true`

Comment: This works in Unity because of some questionable design decisions on Unity's class library. If you were using C# with, say, .NET, your code wouldn most likely not compile.

Comment: This style of assigning a value inside an `if()` test is valid in C# and other C like languages. Due to the probability that you actually wanted a comparison, most C compilers will issue a warning unless you wrap the assignment in an extra pair of brackets like `if((ScriptB.giveCookie = true) ||`. If only C# had a similar warning....

Answer (score 2):

Since you're evaluating a **comparison** you have to use `==` instead of `=` (which is an assignment operator).

Moreover, C# allows to perform something known as [Short Circuiting](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/short-circuit-evaluation-in-c-sharp/) which allows you to evaluate only the minimum amount of conditions from left to right.

In this case you're checking whether ScriptB.giveCookie is true **or** ScriptB is null but checking for the `giveCookie` property if ScriptB is null would throw an error.

You can refactor your code as follows:

```cs
if(ScriptB == null || ScriptB.giveCookie) // == true is not needed
{
    GiveCookie();
}
```

In this way, if ScriptB is null the second condition is not even evaluated and this does not cause errors at runtime.

Comment: You could also write it as `if(ScriptB ?.giveCookie ==  true)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the || operator to compare Booleans only. = is used to assign value, if you want to check if the script is null or if the value is true, you should use ==. You need to understand the basic difference between types of operators.